# Hibernate update non-reference fields of object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I want to develop a CMS using Java, Spring Data/ MVC/ DI , Hibernate defining REST-like API.

I have the following model entities:

- there are multiple `Article`s
- each article has multiple `Section`s
- each section can have subsections and / or `Item`

All these entities have properties of their own (e.g. name, type etc.), but as it is obvious they refer to their aggregated entities. I need to defined CRUD API methods for each such entity.

I decided to stray a bit from dogmatical REST and when I do modify I need to pass in only the entity-specific properties (like name, type etc.), but would not affect the aggregations. Thus I have endpoints like:

- post `/articles` - creates an article, no sections
- put `/articles/{article_id}` - updates basic article properties, does not affect sections
- post `/articles/{article_id}/sections` - creates a section in the article
- delete `/articles/{article_id}/sections/{section_id}` - removes the section from the article
- put `/articles/{article_id}/sections/{section_id}` - updates basic section properties, does not affect owning article properties, nor aggregated sections and items
- etc...

So my question is:

When I receive a modify request I get all basic properties of the element along with owning entity identifier. How can I effectively combine those with the existing relations in the database, so that I keep all of them and modify the basic properties without the need of copying over all properties one by one. Here is an example for the article-section relation.

```
public void modifySection(int articleId, int sectionId, Section section) {
    assert(article.owns(sectionId));
    Section dbSection = sectionDao.findOne(sectionId);
    copyOverProperties(section, dbSection); // this is the thing I do not know how to do
    sectionDao.save(dbSection);
}
```

Comment: Hibernates merge method will do that for you.

Comment: @WeareBorg - can you please link me. Feel free to post an answer

Comment: Are you looking foe something like http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html or http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html?

Comment: @AlanHay neither as i am faced with two instances of the same type

Answer (score 1):

You require hibernates session.merge(object_name);

Link : [From Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29)

Examples from edit functionality of our webapp :

```
   @Repository
    public class GroupCanvasDAOImpl implements GroupCanvasDAO {

        private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Autowired
        public GroupCanvasDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
    @Override
        public void editGroupCanvas(GroupCanvas groupCanvas) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            GroupCanvas groupCanvas1 = (GroupCanvas) session.get(GroupCanvas.class, groupCanvas.getMcanvasid());

//  Below 2 steps are not necessary if object was retrieved from DB and //then persisted back-again. If it was newly created to replace an //old-one, then the below 2 lines are needed.
    groupCanvas.setGroupAccount(groupCanvas1.getGroupAccount());
                groupCanvas.setCanvasowner(groupCanvas1.getCanvasowner());
                session.merge(groupCanvas);
                session.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

If this is not what you are looking for, kindly let me know, I will delete my answer.

Comment: So in this session I have to reset all relation fields, instead of all basic properties. Still, not the best situation for me, because I want to create a generic method that could address all kinds of relations I have. Still, please keep the answer - I believe it is useful.

Comment: You don't need to reset all relation fields... Presume this situation, you call an object which is associated with others, call its getById(int id);. Then you edited the object, changed something other then primary_key. Then you can directly call session.merge(object_name) and your relations will be maintained.

Comment: I am resetting relations as our front-end code creates objects to be edited sometimes(don't ask, long story)... That's why I have to reset them. Got it?

Comment: Ok ,but then as I receive the new values in another bean instance (from Spring MVC) and I have to do something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) between this instance and the one I got from `getById(int id)`. I need to omit the relations from this copying, where my question actually resides.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, in one bean instance(First), you call getById(int id); and then you pass the object to another bean instance(Second), then it's edited and again returned back to the 'First' instance for update. If that's the case, still you can use session.merge and omit the relations as you are copying the properties or cloning the bean(I would prefer cloning for this situation). Did I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: Web services. I get Json communicated. I deserialize it, thus I get instance 1. It has basic properties as well as fk ids, but it has nothing to do with the peristencecontext yet. The second instance I load from db with `getById(int id)` based on the id I received in the call. Now I need to merge the newly communicated properties to the DB instance and persist it. I want to avoid copying over all properties, hardcoded one-by-one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95677/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-boris-strandjev).